# Unable to detect ivr

Tags: ivr, vonage

We want to provide communication feature between tutor and user by conference call, so followings are the steps:

1. First, we will call the tutor.
2. We will ask a question to the tutor, for ex. please press 1 to start the communication with the user.
3. once tutor press 1 then will join the user with the tutor in the same call.

   ```
    <?php
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

    $keypair = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Keypair(
      file_get_contents('private.key__'),
      '############################'
    );

    $client = new \Nexmo\Client($keypair);

    $ncco = [
      [
        "action"=> "talk",
        "text"=> "Welcome to a Voice API I V R. ",
        "voiceName"=> "Amy",
        "bargeIn"=> false
      ],
      [
        "action"=> "talk",
        "text"=> "please press 1 to communicate with user",
        "voiceName"=> "Amy",
        "bargeIn"=> true
      ],
      [
        "action"=> "input",
        "submitOnHash"=> true,
        "eventUrl"=> ["https://studentzmojo.com/answer"]
      ]
    ];
    $call = new \Nexmo\Call\Call();
    $call->setTo('91XXXXXXXXX')
      ->setFrom('91XXXXXXXXX')
      ->setNcco($ncco);

    $response = $client->calls()->create($call);
    echo"<pre>";print_r($response);die;
   echo $response->getId();

   ?>
   ```

Comment: You've stated what your code does, but you haven't said what happens when you run your code. Please can you edit your question so that I can work out what's wrong, so I can maybe help fix it!

Comment: So the first call is working fine (like we are calling tutor first) but when system asks to tutor "please press 1 to communicate with user" and tutor press 1 then we are not received any response at eventUrl (' https://studentzmojo.com/answer'), So can you please suggest me, If I'm doing something wrong and I just want some response when tutor press 1 so I can join the user in the call with tutor using conference feature.

Comment: When the call gets to the end of the NCCO, it will hang up. You probably want to follow the input action with another talk "please wait while we connect you" and then maybe some hold music or something. If the user doesn't press the `#` button to submit the input, it will wait for the timeout and without another action, the call will end before that happens